# Cannot login after enabling pam_faillock module

Tags: debian, ubuntu, pam

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I enable the `pam_faillock` module by adding the following two lines in the `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` file.

```
auth     [default=die]  pam_faillock.so authfail                           
auth     sufficient     pam_faillock.so authsucc
```

I add these lines below

```
auth  [success=2 default=ignore]   
pam_unix.so nullok
```

And above:

```
auth  [success=1 default=ignore]  
psm_sss.so use_first_pass
```

The `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` is posted below with my changes commented out.

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok
#auth    [default=die]               pam_faillock.so authfail
#auth    sufficient                  pam_faillock.so authsucc
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_sss.so use_first_pass
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional            pam_cap.so 
auth    required  pam_faildelay.so delay=4000000
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

After I add these lines I uncomment the following lines from `/etc/security/faillock.conf`

```
audit
silent
deny = 3
fail_interval = 900
unlock_time = 0
```

After these changes I reboot, when I try to login after reboot it tells me the password is incorrect. (Yes I have verified it's not a bad password) I am not the strongest in this area and I am unsure what is causing this to happen.

Comment: Please show the full PAM configuration files where you added the `faillock` entries. Order of entries is vitally important, so showing just the lines you added isn't sufficient information.

Comment: I have added the entries from /etc/pam.d/common-auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've uncommented your lines and put them in what I think is now the right place. I've also moved one or two of the other lines around to fix the authentication flow.

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=4 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok
auth    [success=3 default=ignore]  pam_sss.so use_first_pass
auth    [default=die]               pam_faillock.so authfail
auth    required                    pam_faildelay.so delay=4000000
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite                   pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required                    pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional                    pam_cap.so 
auth    sufficient                  pam_faillock.so authsucc
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

Notice I have also changed the first two `auth` lines - the `[success=N]` tells PAM to jump N rules on success, so a success from `pam_unix` or `pam_sss` will jump to `pam_permit`, and either failing will take you to the `pam_faillock`, `pam_faildelay`, and `pam_deny`.

**I can't test this because I don't have `pam_faillock` installed.** So to test this, first open a root shell on your system and do not touch it except to make changes to PAM configuration files.

With a second terminal session, try logging in, etc., and test that it works.

If it doesn't, you have the first session open ready to revert your changes. Do not close down this session until you are absolutely sure you have a working configuration.